# How to benchmark custom interface using google benchmark

Tags: c++, google-benchmark

since I can't find really good resource or documentation besides what's on the github readme, I'll ask the community here.

Assuming that I have an interface called `Base`, and multiple derived types.
I want to benchmark a virtual function `Foo` of all derived types with the same function and the same argument passed to `Foo`.
For each derived type I want to call `Foo` multiple times in a single benchmark with varying arguments passed from an `std::vector<std::size_t>`.

Also some of my constructor of derived types takes extra arguments, how should I deal with it?

The easiest thing to do as I see it, is to use templated benchmark and pass to:

```cpp
const std::vector<std::size_t> v {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(func, Derived1, v);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(func, Derived2, v);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(func, Derived3, v);
...
```

I don't feel this is the correct way to do this since for each derived type with different constructor signature I would need to have different benchmark function which is almost identical to the previous one.

What would be the proper way to benchmark this?

**UPDATE*:
The way I solved this is as follows:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Base> GetObj(const std::size_t index)
{
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        return std::make_unique<Derived1>(...);
    case 1:
        return std::make_unique<Derived2>(...);
    ...
    }
}

void func(benchmark::State& state)
{
    auto r = state.range();
    auto object = GetObj(r);
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        ...
    }
}
BENCHMARK(func)->DenseRange(0,5);
```

But what I don't like about it is that the name of the benchmark tests is of the pattern `func/0-5` and I would like it to be `func/Derived1`, `func/Derived2` and so on.. any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Solutions are answers, not questions. Please post your solution as an answer, and remove it from the question. **YES**, you are encouraged to answer your own questions!

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Unless I can overcome this little annoyance caused by my solution, I do not wish to make it the best answer or propose it. I post it as an update to my OP so others could see my progress and build upon it. If there's another solution that doesn't introduce this issue then I will be accepting it as the solution, otherwise I'm just updating my question since in my eyes it's not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is pretty much correct. If you want to avoid the multiple benchmark functions, move the core of the benchmark to a separate function and call it from each of the per-type ones.  Something like:

```cpp
static void Benchmark(Base* b, benchmark::State& st) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    b->DoTheThing()
  }
}

void BM_Foo(benchmark::State& st) {
  Foo f;
  Benchmark(&f, st);
}

BENCHMARK(BM_Foo);
```

If you want to be more sophisticated, you could use the `RegisterBenchmark` function to register things more flexibly. Something like:

```cpp
auto BM_base = [](benchmark::State& st, auto inputs, Base* b) { /* ... */ };

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  const std::vector<std::size_t> v = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
  benchmark::RegisterBenchmark("foo", BM_base, v, new Foo());
  benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
  return benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
}
```

As an aside, should v be set as the `Arg`s when the benchmark is registered?

Comment: I ended up having one benchmark function that pulls pointers to base from a helper function based on index. The index is passed using `DenseRange`, this way I can have only one function.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question with my solution and also a new question that arose from this implementation. Would love to hear your opinion on how to achieve what I'm looking for on my updated question.

Comment: you should be using templated benchmarks or one of the solutions in my answer which will give you the naming you want.